Is it possible to interrupt the power supply of a USB port?
Is it possible on Debian 12, using only the core utilities, to interrupt the power supply of a USB port directly on the PC, So that I can turn the power supply on and off as needed?
I don't mean deactivating the USB port, because that only stops signal/data transmission, but the power remains on.
Is it possible without using special USB hubs, smart USB hubs, other hardware or software parts?
Edit:
I have found answers and questions on several Stack Exchange sites, but all of them only relate to disabling, and the most posts are almost very old and because the kernel and other things have changed during that time.
The answers do not solve my problem, so with core utilities and without smart devices or other.
With the answers, I can only disable devices and not cut off power.
I just want to know if it’s possible with my requirements, otherwise, I have to do it with smart devices.

This question is similar to: Turning off power to usb port. Or turn off power to entire usb subsystem. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @Marcus Müller The post is almost 10 years old, and the answers do not solve my problem, so without core utilities and smart devices. With the answers, I can only disable devices and not cut off power. I just want to know if it’s possible with my requirements, otherwise, I have to do it with smart devices. I have found answers and questions on several Stack Exchange sites, but all of them only relate to disabling.

I've had success in the past with  regular USB hubs, where disabling the hub removes power to all devices connected to it.

@Stéphane Chazelas Thank you for the answer. I'll try that tomorrow. I have several cheap standard usb hubs with 4 and 8 ports. If that works, the problem is solved. I'll give some feedback afterwards.

@Stéphane Chazelas After you replied, I couldn't wait until tomorrow ^^ and tried it out immediately with 2 old hubs and even with a USB switch. I can disable USB sticks or devices recognized by the system, but it doesn't work with a USB LED or USB fan, so the power is always on. It seems to depend on luck if you get the right hub. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, but thanks again

For the record, since you were asking about built-in USB ports – those still count as being on a hub (the "root hub"), and the same method would still apply to them as well. I've had success with uhubctl on an older laptop, but generally no success with newer ones. (Sometimes the root hub will flat out lie about turning power off; uhubctl 'works' on my HP servers but has no effect.) Regardless, this doesn't change the technical validity of the 10-year-old answer – the 'port power control' USB control messages did not change over those 10 years, the problem is with hardware not supporting them.

@grawity Thanks for the info. Since it’s a hardware issue and doesn't have general applicability, that means you have to be lucky to find the right device that might work., I’ve now decided to try it with a smart USB hub or a smart socket with USB and timer control.
